# transform translate3d rendering order with webkit/gecko/blink

Tags: css, webkit, gecko, blink

I'm having an issue with something.

I'm using a parallax plugin (https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax) and trying to put interactive popups in layers of the scene. These popups must have positions relative to their respective layers in the parallax context, but they must be rendered on top of everything else.

I had no issues achieving this with chrome: wagerfield's parallax plugin set a translate3d attribute on each layer, and the z-axis is always left to 0px. So I just had to add this to my popups:

```
transform: translate3d(0px,0px,1px);
```

It works for Chrome: the popups are rendered above the layers. However, on Safari and Firefox, nothing changes.

Any idea how I would achieve this on browsers other than Chrome ?